# sendmail send email in Rails only after I had pressed ctrl + c when I have said rails s

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sendmail, actionmailer

In my development.rb I have:

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
    config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
    :location => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
    :arguments => '-i'
}
```

I removed -t option because it didn't allow me to send email.
When I start the console and go to my app and send email the email is send but only after I press ctrl + C. My guess is that this is happening because sendmail creates a process and the parent process - rails server - waits for it to finish and ctrl + c is telling to the parent process that the child is done. Is this right? Do you know how to fix it so that I don't have to press ctrl + c? I user rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.9.2. Thanks in advance for all answers and please excuse my English. It is not my native language

Comment: why do you want to send mails in development?

Comment: I want to send emails in development so I can test them

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails in development to look at them by hand if they work, is generally not a clean way of testing.

[This Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers) covers testing for controllers too. Setting up tests for your emails is pretty easy (from the linked [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers)):

```
#unit test
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  tests UserMailer
  test "invite" do
    @expected.from    = 'me@example.com'
    @expected.to      = 'friend@example.com'
    @expected.subject = "You have been invited by #{@expected.from}"

    assert_equal @expected.encoded, UserMailer.create_invite('me@example.com',     'friend@example.com', @expected.date).encoded
  end
end
```

and a sample functional test (also from the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers)):

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "invite friend" do
    assert_difference 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', +1 do
      post :invite_friend, :email => 'friend@example.com'
    end
    invite_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last

    assert_equal "You have been invited by me@example.com", invite_email.subject
    assert_equal 'friend@example.com', invite_email.to[0]
    assert_match(/Hi friend@example.com/, invite_email.body)
  end
end
```